# What are these characters (�pret�) and how do I fix this?

Tags: character

I just don't know where I'm supposed to ask this, I don't know much about computers, feel free to direct me to the right forum, I searched for this but could not find out where to post.

Anyhow, I was doing search and came across this website:

http://tonioc.free.fr/dico/dico.txt

I was using Firefox.  How do I fix this, use a different browser or is there an addon or something?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check this site: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BF%BD

This question mark character is a replacement character. Meaning that the website you are visiting is either using characters not supported by the font itself of the browser does not understand them. I tried with chrome and didn't get any result too. The characters are unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the character encoding to Occident (windows-1252). There is an option inside Firefox.